# printing elements for file system tree

Tags: functional-programming, tree, ocaml

I have this tree:

```
type filename = string
type content = Bytes.t

type fs = 
  | FileContent of content 
  | Folder of (filename * fs) list

let f1 = FileContent(Bytes.of_string "poum")
let f2 = FileContent(Bytes.of_string "think")
let f3 = Folder [("f1.mp3", f1); ("f2.mp3", f2)]
let f4 = FileContent (Bytes.of_string "text")
let f5 = Folder [("my music", f3); ("t.txt", f4)]
```

and I want to write a function `iter` with this signature: `fs -> unit` such that `iter f` prints the names of the elements in `f` and recursively applies the call to its elements. The order preferred is not important.

The expected output is:

```
my music
f1.mp3
f2.mp3
t.txt
```

I have started this way:

```
let rec iter f = 
  match f with
  | FileContent c -> ()
  | Folder ((n, f1)::t) -> ...
  | Folder [] -> ()
```

my problem is that I can recursively call `f1` and so on, but how to do that for the list as well? Also `Stdlib.Printf.printf c` shows red error squiggly line under `c`.

**Update**

In a different way, I want to have a `traverse func f` function (signature: `(content -> content option) -> fs -> fs`), such that `traverse` returns the same structure as `f` where the leaf `e = content` can be modified according to the value of `func e`, and if this value is `None` we keep `e`, otherwise we return the value of the option returned. Building on the solution of the above question, I tried to this:

```
let rec traverse func f = 
  match f with
  | FileContent c -> 
    begin
      match func c with
      | Some e -> FileContent e
      | None -> FileContent c
    end
  | Folder ((n, f1)::t) -> 
    traverse func f1;
    traverse func @@ Folder t
  | Folder [] -> Folder []
```

But the problem is how to return structure `fs` within `Folder ((n, f1)::t) ->`  , how to do that?

Comment: Have you looked at `List.iter`?

Comment: Indeed, but I am not sure how to use it

Comment: If you're just printing a string, rather than use `Stdlib.Printf.printf` just use `Stdlib.print_string` or `Stdlib.print_endline`.

Comment: What expression are you evaluating where you expect that output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've given us this start, which shows that we clearly don't care about printing file content.

> ```
> let rec iter f = 
>   match f with
>   | FileContent c -> ()
>   | Folder ((n, f1)::t) -> ...
>   | Folder [] -> ()
> ```

First off, you'll want to print the name of the file. That's easy:

```
let rec iter f = 
  match f with
  | FileContent c -> ()
  | Folder ((n, f1)::t) -> 
    print_endline n
  | Folder [] -> ()
```

But there's no recursion, so that prints the first filename and then stops. Next let's recursively print the file contents.

```
let rec iter f = 
  match f with
  | FileContent c -> ()
  | Folder ((n, f1)::t) -> 
    print_endline n;
    iter f1
  | Folder [] -> ()
```

But what do we do with `t`? Well, we recursively print it with iter.

```
let rec iter f = 
  match f with
  | FileContent c -> ()
  | Folder ((n, f1)::t) -> 
    print_endline n;
    iter f1;
    iter t
  | Folder [] -> ()
```

Well, now this doesn't compile, because `iter` expects a `fs` value, not a list, which is what this is. If we consider that `Folder` wraps a list, then the solution is to rewrap this list as a folder.

```
let rec iter f = 
  match f with
  | FileContent c -> ()
  | Folder ((n, f1)::t) -> 
    print_endline n;
    iter f1;
    iter @@ Folder t
  | Folder [] -> ()
```

Now, recognizing that the actual file contents don't matter, we can streamline this a bit:

```
let rec iter f =
  match f with
  | FileContent _ | Folder [] -> ()
  | Folder ((n, f1)::t) ->
    print_endline n;
    iter f1;
    iter @@ Folder t
```

---

As for your additional question (which should be it's own question) you seemingly want to *map* your tree to another tree, optionally updating file contents.

So let's use the name `map` *and* let's slightly rearrange your patterns. Keep in mind your function must always return the same type, so if we have a `Folder`, the *result* needs to be a `Folder`.

We can recursively call `map func` on the tail of the list after we wrap it in the `Folder` constructor. We then use pattern-matching to extract the resulting list.

```
let rec map func = function
  | Folder [] -> Folder []
  | FileContent c ->
    (match func c with
     | Some e -> FileContent e
     | None   -> FileContent c)
  | Folder ((n, f1)::t) ->
    let Folder t' = map func @@ Folder t in
    Folder ((n, map func f1) :: t')
```

```
# f5
  |> map 
       (fun c -> 
          if String.starts_with ~prefix:"t" (String.of_bytes c) then 
            Some (Bytes.of_string "replaced") 
          else 
            None);;
- : fs =
Folder
 [("my music",
   Folder
    [("f1.mp3", FileContent (Bytes.of_string "poum"));
     ("f2.mp3", FileContent (Bytes.of_string "replaced"))]);
  ("t.txt", FileContent (Bytes.of_string "replaced"))]
```